# How to interrupt a thread in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading, sigint

I've encountered an uninterruptable code in Python 2.7.

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def fun():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Timer(1, fun).start()
```

First, how come it is uninterruptable? (It ignores SIGINT)
In Python 3 this code interrupts fine.

Second, what changes should I make for it to respond to SIGINT before it finishes the loop?
In my actual case, it's an infinite loop :.(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet sure why does it happen, but this phenomenon is mentioned in Python 3.2 bug fix report.

I found a workaround by unfolding the following code:

```
def fun():
    while True:
        ... my code ...
        sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Timer(1, fun).start()
```

Into:

```
def fun():
    ... my code ...
    threading.Timer(0.1, fun).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Timer(1, fun).start()
```